# Solving an equation involving $e^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How do I solve this question

$$ e^{-x^2/2} = 2.25 $$

I am stuck on this question but have tried to split the exponential function

$$ e^{x^2} \cdot e^{-1/2} = 2.25 $$

$$ e^{x^2} + e^{-1/2} = 2.25 $$

Am I on the right track? If not, how do I go on from there?

I understand that if I $\ln$ the equation I would get an error since I can't square root a negative number.

Comment: $e^{ab} \neq e^ae^b$

Comment: Take the logarithm first.

Comment: First of all, we have $e^{-x^2/2}\leq1$ for all *real* $x$, and so, any solution to your equation necessarily lies in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$. Next, in general $e^{ab}\neq e^{a}e^{b}$ and $e^a e^b \neq e^a + e^b$. Finally, I changed the title to be more suggesting and reformulated some of the equations. Hope this is to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x^2\geq0$, we have $-x^2/2\leq0$, and it follows (by monotonicity of $e^t$) that $e^{-x^2/2}\leq1<2.25$.

There is no real solution to this equation.